# Is RTSP Announce used to send video from Client to Server. And is it what is happening below?

Tags: video, rtsp

I was playing around with [Libstreaming](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming) and ran its Example 3 which sends Video stream to the Wowza server from mobile.
Now What i know from my limited knowledge of RTSP is that `Announce` can be used to send video from client to server. But `SETUP` can only be send from the client that is the peer who will be receiving the video (but here it is sent by the Mobile - the sender).

```
ANNOUNCE rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Content-Length: 257
Content-Type: application/sdp 

v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 null
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 192.169.6.151
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=420014;sprop-parameter-sets=J0IAFKaCxMQ=,KM48gA==;
a=control:trackID=1

RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
CSeq: 1
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Streaming Server",  nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669"
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

ANNOUNCE rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
Content-Length: 257
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"
Session: 902878796
Content-Type: application/sdp 

v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 null
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 192.169.6.151
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=420014;sprop-parameter-sets=J0IAFKaCxMQ=,KM48gA==;
a=control:trackID=1
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

SETUP rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=5002-5003;mode=receive
CSeq: 3
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 4 Mar 2016 11:31:22 IST
Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=5002-5003;mode=receive;source=192.169.6.151;server_port=6974-6975
Date: Fri, 4 Mar 2016 11:31:22 IST
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

RECORD rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
Range: npt=0.000-
CSeq: 4
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Range: npt=now-
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 7
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 8
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 8
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 9
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 9
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 10
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 10
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 11
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 11
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 12
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 12
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 13
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 13
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 14
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 14
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 15
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 15
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

OPTIONS rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 16
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 16
Server: Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.0 build17748
Cache-Control: no-cache
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, OPTIONS, ANNOUNCE, RECORD, GET_PARAMETER
Supported: play.basic, con.persistent
Session: 902878796;timeout=60

TEARDOWN rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 17
Content-Length: 0
Session: 902878796
Authorization: Digest username="User1",realm="Streaming Server",nonce="9d9e1266ebfe1e5d8f48432af4b97669",uri="rtsp://192.169.6.151:1935/live/android_test",response="93271d1b62097f92d85b34f65cdd89af"
```

Questions:

2. The `SETUP` command is being sent to receiver, is it right (according to RTSP Standard).
3. Is the communication that is happening specific to Wowza ?
4. Do Live555 or Gstreamer support client somehow sending video to them.

Note: First question is the title.